# Firebase - Regras de segurança somente leitura

Tags: firebase

Coloquei várias imagens no Storage, do Firebase. Depois criei um banco de dados no Firestore Database, que remete às imagens do Storage. Comecei a usar com a regra de segurança default de lá, que era de leitura e gravação liberadas pra todos. Então comecei a receber mensagens, do Firebase, dizendo que as regras não eram seguras. Troquei, então, essas regras para a seguinte:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
   match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

Fiz o mesmo para o Storage. Só permito leitura.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

Pergunta: Qual é a regra para permitir apenas leitura, pra qualquer usuário, sem precisar criar usuários? Essa que coloquei está correta? Por que recebo a mensagem de que as regras não são seguras?

Agradeço!

Answer (score -1):

o firebase parte do pré suposto que todas aplicações deveriam ser autenticadas mas isso não é necessariamente uma regra. não há problema algum em manter o Firestore e o Storage com permissões abertas dependendo do modelo da aplicação.
No entanto é importante ressaltar que leituras no Firestore e Storage são cobradas! logo se suas regras estão abertas alguém pode de maneira inadivertida ou maliciosa fazer milhões requisições
e isso pode te custar caro, caso tenha a opção pay as you go (blaze) de pagamento. nessas situações é importante criar cotas de acesso em: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?service=cloudfunctions.googleapis.com&usage=ALL&project=_

Você pode desabilitar os emails e alertas no console do Firebase:

> 1. Clique no sininho   <kbd>Alertas</kbd> no canto direito superior do console e depois em configurações.
> 2. Procure o serviço do Firestore e do Storage.
> 3. Marque o ou desmarque o que for relevante para você tanto por email tanto pelo alertas no console.

Comment: Obrigada, Paulo. Acabei por criar usuário anônimo. Vi que o limite de criação é bem alto, então foi o melhor a fazer. Obrigada pela informação!